# Is this a correct way to url encode / is this server handling decoding correctly?

Tags: javascript, security, urlencode

From a browser I'm making a request to `someurl.com/route?url=<some other url>`.

This works fine for most urls. The issue arises when a non-ascii character comes into play.

Say the url I want to pass as a query parameter is: `https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/また`.

So I `encodeURIComponent` my url and now I have: `https%3A%2F%2Fja.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F`

and send off a request to: `someurl.com/route?url=https%3A%2F%2Fja.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F`

...only to receive an 400 bad request error. For the server to accept my input and handle it correctly, I have to encode the `また` part of the url and then re-encode the whole url. I end up doing `encodeURIComponent(encodeURI(url))` which results in:

`https%3A%2F%2Fja.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25E3%2581%25BE%25E3%2581%259F`

You can see that the `また` part is double encoded. I'm am trying to decide if this is something that there is a risk in doing.

1) I would expect to encode once. Is it incorrect or "wrong" to be url encoding more than once?

2) If so is this indicative of a security issue? Does this mean the server is decoding more than once?

Comment: What's going on server-side?  Double-encoding is not required, and will actually make this problem worse.

Comment: I don't know. I am sure the URI is being accessed but beyond that... Why do you say double encoding will make it worse? That it will break some URIs?